# Apache + Delphi XE7 + Datasnap. Problemas com a memória

Tags: delphi, apache, datasnap

Desenvolvi um programa com Apache, Delphi XE7 e Datasnap. Meu httpd.exe do Apache consome memória até dar a mensagem "Out of Memory" então eu preciso reiniciar o Apache.

Configurei o ServerModule (componentes FireDac, Mysql) e o WebModule para executar uma simples consulta.

No Cliente eu tenho um `DBGrid` que mostra os resultado da Query

Com o Gerenciador de Tarefas aberto e monitorando a memória:

- Ao conectar e desconectar o `TSQLConnection` ou abrir e fechar o `TClientDataSet` a memória aumenta.

O que eu já tentei fazer:

Executei o *Pascal Analyzer* procurando vazamentos de memória mas está ok, tentei desligar o keep alive do Apache mas não fez diferença, já usei todos os tipos de ciclo de vida do WebModule (Session, Server and Invocation) mas o problema persiste.

Desde já Obrigado.

Comment: Quando é que vocês utilizaram este comando? Pelo fato de estar em uma aplicação `datasnap` servidora, isso não pode causar nenhum problema quando usando uma aplicação multi-camadas onde cada cliente tem a sua thread (`RemoteDatamodule`)?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta o código abaixo, acredito que ajude.

```
procedure TformPrincipal.LimpaMemoria;
var
   MainHandle : THandle;    
begin
   try
      MainHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, GetCurrentProcessID) ;
      SetProcessWorkingSetSize(MainHandle, $FFFFFFFF, $FFFFFFFF) ;
      CloseHandle(MainHandle) ;

   except
   end;

   Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A solução acima é muito boa, mas para ser utilizada no cliente. No servidor, caso pesquisas maiores sejam feitas, vai ser difícil ter memória para todo mundo.

No servidor, dê preferência a usar a menor quantidade possível. Desligue as opções do `FireDac` que criam **cache** das informações e mude o ponteiro do `FireDac` para `unidirecional`. Deixe que o cliente guarde os dados em cache (ou transmita eles via json ou o que quer que seja).

Certifique-se também de utilizar o método `Release` ao invés do método `free`. `Release` remove a memória utilizado pelo cursor (e outros comedores de memória), enquanto o `free` ignora tudo isso.